# Combining entries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how to do the following in SQL. I tried using GROUP BY and HAVING in different ways, but none works.

I have a table like this:

```
Title   Value 1   Value 2 ...
0       3         7
1       4         8
2       5         9
(empty) 6         10
0       1         2
```

Here, `(empty)` is not a string. I just put it there to show that that table cell is `empty(null)`. I want to display this table with only one change. All rows with Title `0 or (empty)` are **"combined"** into a single row, with Title `0` and Value `1 = Sum(all Value 1s)`, Value `2 = Sum(all Value 2s)`. Everything else stays the same. 
So, in the example above, I want to see:

```
Title   Value 1   Value 2 ...  
0       10        19
1       4         8
2       5         9
```

Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: An integer column cannot be empty

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ????

Comment: Amend your schema to take advantage of the appropriate data types.

Comment: @Strawberry: I meant: Why can't integer columns be empty? Is this something special in MySQL? I'd be surprised.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I can't speak for other RDBMSs, but that's certainly the case with MySQL. They can be NULL or 0, but not ''

Comment: @Strawberry: Okay, you take "empty" to mean "empty string" and an integer is not a string obviously. I understand an empty numeric field to mean null, and this is obviously what the OP meant, too: "Here, (empty) is not a string. I just put it there to show that that table cell is empty(**null**)."

Answer (score 3):

This is an aggregation query with a `case`:

```
select (case when title is null or title = 0 then 0 else title end) as title,
       sum(value1) as value1, sum(value2) as value2
from t
group by (case when title is null or title = 0 then 0 else title end)
order by title;
```

If you like, you could also use the logic:

```
select coalesce(title, 0) as title,
       sum(value1) as value1, sum(value2) as value2
from t
group by coalesce(title, 0)
order by title;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
IF(Title ='(empty)',0,Title) AS title_col,
SUM(value1) as Value_1,
SUM(value2) as Value_2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY title_col;
```

**Note:**

If the `Title` column actually holds this string `(empty)` then you can go with this query.

**EDIT:**

If the datatype of the column is `INT` then it can have null value if it's declared as `ALLOW NULL`.

If so then the query would be modified like below:

```
SELECT 
IF(Title IS NULL,0,Title) AS title_col,
SUM(value1) as Value_1,
SUM(value2) as Value_2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY title_col;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, (empty) is not a string. I just put it there to show that that cell is empty.

Comment: Then is it null? Or empty string? By the way what's the datatype of title column?

Comment: Null. Type of column is actually int. The name "title" is misleading, but I didn't choose it.

Comment: okay. Then the answer under edit section should work for you. @AlexVerzea

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I see two queries, one for title records and one for the aggregation of the non-title records. Use `UNION ALL` to glue the two results together:

```
select title, value1, value2
from my table where coalesce(title, 0) <> 0
union all
select 0, sum(value1), sum(value2)
from my table where coalesce(title, 0) = 0
group by title
order by title;
```

(In case that all `title` <> 0 were unique in the table, you could use one single query with `group by coalesce(title, 0)` instead.)

Comment: I already found a solution before you posted, but this one is very good too. Thanks!